# 'in-a my heart' correct, or only 'in my heart'?

Tags: lyrics

There are two different lyrics in the hymn.

> Lord, I want to be a Christian in-a my heart

vs

> Lord, I want to be a Christian in my heart

Is the first correct too or typing error?

Comment: The -a is for cadence, I.E. keeping time :)

Answer (score 4):

> Lord, I want to be a Christian in my heart

is Standard English

> Lord, I want to be a Christian in-a my heart

The "in-a" my heart part sounds like a dialect. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord,_I_Want_to_Be_a_Christian), this hymn was composed by African American slaves in the 1750's, so it is probably a remnant of their dialect.

Comment: I tend to agree. Yet it's ironic, or perhaps telling, that the Wikipedia article does not give the lyrics found on the image of the sheet music!